# Apache poi the file is corrupted

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with apache poi and I create a HSSF workbook and try to open a xlsx file. But when I open with excel, it says the file is corrupted. Here is my code.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test1.xls");
            workbook.write(output);
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HSSF might not work with the newer .xslx file format.  It's pretty old.  I'm not sure it's kept up.  You might do better with Andy Khan's JExcel.

Comment: It is happening same thing, when I try .xls

Comment: Looks like the latest release was 16-Apr-2017; newer than I thought.  What version are you using?  https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.16

Comment: I am using 3.16 which is latest stable version.

Comment: I try to open .xls file wtih notepad++ and there are some strange characters in there

Comment: "Strange characters" - there's your problem.  I don't see an encoding for your output file.  Try adding one (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: Can you open it in Excel? Which version? If you have "strange characters" in it, excel might still be able to open it but poi cannot.

Comment: I resolved it with answer of druid1123, thank you guys.

Comment: All Excel files must have a minimum of one sheet, you need to add at least one before you save!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use XSSFWorkbook for XLSX.

And try creating at least one sheet and see if it is opening correctly.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
try {
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test1.xls");
    workbook.createSheet("sheet1")
    workbook.write(output);
    output.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Even I did not change to XSSF and just added createSheet and it worked.